# in C++, how to use Macro to reduce duplicate code?

Tags: c++

Consider this lines of code:

```
string name = getName();
SomeClass z;

if (name == "a") {
    z.set_name_a("is a");
}
if (name == "b") {
    z.set_name_b("is b");
}
if (name == "c") {
    z.set_name_c("is c");
}
...
```

How do I write a macro function to remove duplicate code?

Specifically I am not sure how to change the function name I am calling(set_name_a, set_name_b, set_name_c, etc)

Comment: Why do you have `set_name_a`, `set_name_b`, `set_name_c` in the first place? What do these functions do?

Comment: How about a more generic `set_name(string name, string str)` function? Then you could do `z.set_name(name, "is " + name)`

Comment: Don't use macros to reduce code duplication. There are so many tools for reducing code duplication in c++, macros should be the last resort.

Comment: Macros are trickier that they look at first glance. Also, when using Macros you are losing type checking most times, that is one of the features that do C++ so safe. My advice for you is to learn first basic c++ tools, as 1/using simple functions with specific parameters, 2/polimorphism and 3/some very basic use of templates. When you master these 3 tools, you will have a wider sight of using C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you prefer to find a better approach to the problem, such as using a hash table.  But since you asked about macros, the usual disclaimers apply (macros are bad, error prone, have poor error messages since the compiler reports on expanded code, have duplicate argument evaluation problems, can bleed into surrounding code if not careful, and you will be scorned and ridiculed by co-workers, and so on).

This will "work" for you:

```
#define PASTE(A,B) A##B
#define CHECK_SET_NAME(X, Y) if (name == #X) { PASTE(z.set_name_, X)(Y); }

CHECK_SET_NAME(a, "is a")
CHECK_SET_NAME(b, "is b")
CHECK_SET_NAME(c, "is c")
```

$g++ -E macro.cpp

```
if (name == "a") { z.set_name_a("is a"); }
if (name == "b") { z.set_name_b("is b"); }
if (name == "c") { z.set_name_c("is c"); }
```

But I wouldn't recommend it.  How can this go wrong?

```
if (x == 10)
    CHECK_SET_NAME(a, "is a");
else
    foo();
```

This is misleading code since it expands to mean this:

```
if (x == 10) {
    if (name == "a") { 
        z.set_name_a("is a"); 
    }
    else foo();
}
```

We could update the macro to fix it:

```
#define CHECK_SET_NAME(X, Y) \
    if (name == #X) { PASTE(z.set_name_, X)(Y); } else {}
```

It gets more and more complicated to handle the error cases, and it is hard to read.  So really, really, really strive to avoid macros when there are better alternatives.  (I'm not 100% against macros, but they are WAY over-used IMHO.)

Comment: Scorned? Oh heavens no. I take the advice of Lawrence Tureaud and I pity the foo.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using macros. In your case, it is much better to use `switch`.

Anyways, here is a macro:

```
#define SET_NAME(obj, comp, set) if( comp == #set ) obj.set_name_##set("is "#set)
```

*# to stringify*

*## to add its value as a code*

Using:

```
    string name = getName();
    SomeClass z;
    SET_NAME(z, name, a);
    SET_NAME(z, name, b);
```